# Difference between consecutive rows in SQL, inclusive of the first and last row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get the successive differences of rows of data in SQL, including differences between first and last row and `0`.

I have two tables that look like this

```
+------------+-------+     +------------+-------+
| Date       | Name  |     | Date       | Value |
+------------+-------+     +------------+-------+
| 2019-10-10 | AAA   |     | 2019-10-11 | 100   |
| 2019-10-11 | BBB   |     | 2019-10-12 | 150   |
| 2019-10-12 | CCC   |     | 2019-10-14 | 300   |
| 2019-10-13 | DDD   |     +------------+-------+
| 2019-10-14 | EEE   |
| 2019-10-15 | FFF   |
+------------+-------+
```

The end result I'm looking for is

```
+------------+-------+-------+---------------+------------+
| Date       | Name  | Value | PreviousValue | Difference |
+------------+-------+-------+---------------+------------+
| 2019-10-11 | BBB   | 100   | 0             | 100        |
| 2019-10-12 | CCC   | 150   | 100           | 50         |
| 2019-10-14 | EEE   | 300   | 150           | 150        |
| 2019-10-15 | FFF   | 0     | 300           | -300       |
+------------+-------+-------+---------------+------------+
```

I can get the first row by using `LAG`, but I don't quite know how to get the last row at the same time.

```
SELECT
    d.[Date],
    d.[Name],
    v.[Value],
    [PreviousValue] = COALESCE(LAG(v.[Value) OVER (ORDER BY v.[Date]), 0)
    [PreviousLossAmount] = v.[Value] - COALESCE(LAG(v.[Value) OVER (ORDER BY v.[Date]), 0)
FROM
    [Dates] d
LEFT JOIN
    [Values] v
ON
    d.[Date] = v.[Date]
```

Note that in reality, my tables are more complex, and I'd need to group and partition by multiple columns.

Comment: ... Why is `'2019-10-13'` excluded from the result table?  What makes it different than `'2019-10-15'` - just not being the last row?  For that matter, why exclude `'2019-10-10'`?

Comment: I'm only interested in things in the `[Values]` table. Could ignore the dates table entirely if needed. But it might be difficult to get the date of `2019-10-15` without it.

Comment: That you include `Name` suggests you need at least some data from the `Date` table.... Otherwise, do you have a calendar table you can join to, to get all dates from?  Also, if your query is actually "more complicated", then we're going to need to see the whole thing if the existing answers won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a subquery, you can `LEFT JOIN`, and use `ROW_NUMBER()` to identify the last record. Then in the outer query you can filter out rows that did not match in the `LEFT JOIN` while allowing the last record.

Other considerations:

- you just need to order `LAG()` by `d.[Date]` instead of `v.[Date]`. This properly handles the case when the `left join` comes up empty (ie when `v.[Date]` is `null`).
- You also want to use `COALESCE()` on `v.[Value]`, since this may come up `null` too.

Query:

```
SELECT
    [Date],
    [Name],
    [Value],
    [PreviousValue],
    [PreviousLossAmount]
FROM (
    SELECT
        d.[Date],
        d.[Name],
        [Value] = COALESCE(v.[Value], 0),
        [PreviousValue] = COALESCE(LAG(v.[Value]) OVER (ORDER BY d.[Date]), 0),
        [PreviousLossAmount] = COALESCE(v.[Value], 0) 
            - COALESCE(LAG(v.[Value]) OVER (ORDER BY d.[Date]), 0),
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY d.[Date] DESC),
        vDate = v.[Date]
    FROM [Dates] d
    LEFT JOIN [Values] v ON d.[Date] = v.[Date]
) t
WHERE vDate IS NOT NULL OR RN = 1
ORDER BY [Date]
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c9c809754a14168b8a48717297b4b575)**:

```
Date                | Name | Value | PreviousValue | PreviousLossAmount
:------------------ | :--- | ----: | ------------: | -----------------:
11/10/2019 00:00:00 | BBB  |   100 |             0 |                100
12/10/2019 00:00:00 | CCC  |   150 |           100 |                 50
14/10/2019 00:00:00 | EEE  |   300 |             0 |                300
15/10/2019 00:00:00 | FFF  |     0 |           300 |               -300
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want:

```
select d.[Date], d.[Name], v.[Value],
       PreviousValue = COALESCE(LAG(v.[Value) OVER (ORDER BY v.[Date]), 0)
       PreviousLossAmount]= v.[Value] - COALESCE(LAG(v.[Value) OVER (ORDER BY v.[Date]), 0)
from dates d join
     [Values] v
     on d.[Date] = v.[Date]
union all
select top (1) d.date, d.name, 0 as value, v.value, - v.value
from dates d cross join
     (select top (1) v.*
      from values v
      order by v.date desc
     ) v
order by d.date;
```

Comment: Do you have ideas on this would work if I need to group by other columns? The example is a little simplified. In reality there are more columns to group by, so `TOP 1` won't work. And I can't order by in subquery.

Comment: @KrisHarper . .  It is only possible to answer the question that you have actually asked.  If you have a different question, ask it as a *new* question with appropriate sample data and desired results.

Comment: I mentioned at the bottom of the question that my case was more complicated than my minimum example.